# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm building a rails application where I want to redirect the user to a `#show` action when they click on a index table's row.

For this I'm trying to use Jquery in my coffeescript file. Here's the relevant code

### index.html.erb:

```
<% @campaign.each do |campaign| %>
    <tr data-link="<%= campaign_path(campaign) %>">
        <td><%= campaign.campaign_name %></td>
        <td><%= campaign.start_date %></td>
        <td><%= campaign.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "delete", campaign, class:"btn btn-default btn-xs", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %></td>
     </tr>
<% end %>
```

### campaigns.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $("tr[data-link]").click ->
    window.location.replace($(this).data("link"));
```

But once I run this I keep on seeing this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I have installed `jquery-rails` gem. Included it in my `application.js` file as well. When my application is rendered, I am seeing the Jquery script tag in the header also

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1"></script>
```

But still I'm seeing this error in the console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at campaigns.self-4617c47e06384e281aa2550caae08f3b4986441d2bfff9b6e3519f0a1e82f3d7.js?body=1:2
at campaigns.self-4617c47e06384e281aa2550caae08f3b4986441d2bfff9b6e3519f0a1e82f3d7.js?body=1:8
(anonymous) @ campaigns.self-4617c47e06384e281aa2550caae08f3b4986441d2bfff9b6e3519f0a1e82f3d7.js?body=1:2
(anonymous) @ campaigns.self-4617c47e06384e281aa2550caae08f3b4986441d2bfff9b6e3519f0a1e82f3d7.js?body=1:8
```

Am I missing anything? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Are you sure the jQuery is loaded before your script? What if you write `jQuery` instead of `$`?

Comment: You might need to add `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->` first.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda I tried adding jQuery instead of $ - it's showing the same error - Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @PatMellon not sure if I'm doing this right. Is this the syntax you're suggesting? 

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
$("tr[data-link]").click ->
window.location.replace($(this).data("link"));

It's still showing the same error though

Comment: Something like `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->`
  `$("tr[data-link]").click ->`
  `window.location.replace($(this).data("link"));`
  `return`
  `return`
 `return`

Comment: @trurohit then you might check in the network tab whether the jQuery script is loaded OK. The fact that you reference it in the HTML doesn't mean that you actually receive from the server.

Comment: @LyoshaKorogoda not sure if that's the problem. When I do $(document) in Chrome console. It's returning the document object. So jQuery script seems to be loaded fine.

Comment: @PatMellon tried the same. Still seeing that error. Probably missing out on some small detail.

Comment: @trurohit -- then you might check once again whether your scripts are loaded in the right order -- i.e the jQuery is already loaded when your script is being executed. You can put a breakpoint in your code and then check the network tab to see whether you have already received the jQuery by the time you are there.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have encountered the same issue, and I realised I must have misunderstood the [official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html):

which I thought in Rails 5.2 (after Rails 5.1), because we have the built-in rails-ujs, we don't need jquery/jquery_ujs anymore.

But I was wrong.

I learned my mistake thru this [article](https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/). After I found the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" issue, all I doubted was "no jquery installed". And after checked many posts, I tried to install [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) to test.

Finally it works.

Yes, we need jquery-rails even in Rails 5.2.

Comment: karl li you are right, you don't need `jquery-ujs` if you are using Rails 5.1 or above because for these versions the correct library is `rails-ujs` but you still need `jquery-rails` if you want to use jquery in your app. `jquery-ujs` and `jquery-rails` are for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

After installing [**`jquery-rails`**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails) then follow the order of `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs 
.....
```

See the [**`Installation`**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#installation)

**Solution From Comment**

I've figured what the problem might be. In my `application.js`, whenever I add `require jquery` - it's breaking my entire application and redirecting all pages to `localhost:3000/undefined`

```
//= require rails-ujs 
//= require jquery 
//= require activestorage 
//= require turbolinks 
//= require_tree .
```

If I remove `require jquery` then it will start working fine again.

Comment: Think I've figured what the problem might be. In my application.js, whenever I add require jQuery - it's breaking my entire application and redirecting all pages to localhost:3000/undefined 

`//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .`

If I remove 'require jQuery' then it will start working fine again.

Comment: I don't know what's happening but the correct order is start with `require jquery` and if you use `require jquery_ujs` then not need to use `require rails-ujs`